# jquery.form update target some of the time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery-plugins

I'm using jQuery.form plugin to `.ajaxSubmit()` between div's popping in and out of view (for logging and sometimes validation purposes). The user can navigate forward and backward. Some of the div's have full form data, in which case I would use the form's parent div as `target:`. However, the other div's contain text and navigation buttons, and they don't need to be updated (just `.hide()` after the ajaxSubmit returns a string indicating the next div id to pop). If I use `$(this).parent('div')` as the target, the whole div gets overwritten with the returned string. This string is only used to populate a hidden element to help with navigating through these screens/div's.

```
$('.CSRForm').submit(function () {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        target: $(this).parent('div'), //for validation purposes on the forms with data
        success: StepCall //to check whether the response is valid for redirecting; and logging
    });
    return false;
});

function StepCall(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    if (responseText != "Negatory") { //"Negatory" would indicate no navigation
        $form.parent('div').css("display", "none"); //doesn't seem to work, neither does "hide()"
        $('#' + responseText).css("display", "block");
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not sure if I'm correctly using `$form` in the .ajaxSubmit `success` callback. Does anyone know? The [website](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxSubmit) isn't clear.

Comment: again, the website isn't really clear. my best guess is that it's a jQuery object wrapper for the form DOM. And I don't know how to use it in this context to get the parent div of said form and hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$form is a wrapped reference to your calling form.

The target `$(this).parent('div')` has been updated with the response, before your success function is called.

Your triggering form has been overwritten with xhr response. The $form.parent in your success method throughs an error, because the reference to $form is no longer valid, ...

Comment: Yep I see that now. Good spotting.

Answer (score 0):

I think $form here would be a jQuery object. I think it would be a good idea to dump that object to the console to find out if the object is there (just for sanity). If you're using firebug I believe using console.log() in your JS should work.

> **success**
>
> Callback function to be invoked after
> the form has been submitted. If a
> 'success' callback function is
> provided it is invoked after the
> response has been returned from the
> server. It is passed the following
> arguments:
>
> 1. 1.) responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the
>    dataType option).
> 2. 2.) statusText
> 3. 3.) xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
> 4. 4.) jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)

So it definately should be passed to you as a jQuery object. I guess if you're using jQuery < 1.4 you're in trouble though.

Comment: I tried console.log(); before and after the line with $form, and switched to the Console tab in Firebug--I didn't see anything but the post. I am using jQuery 1.4.1

Comment: Since, I'm using 1.4.1, it wouldn't be the wrapped form, but the xhr itself, which wouldn't have any way of referencing the parent div